# Messagebundle show Keys instead of value

Tags: jsf, message-bundle

For testing / debugging purpose, I want to show the keys from the message bundle instead of the values in my jsf application. Is that possible?

Example:
My messages_en.properties has following entry:

```
global_today=today
```

example jsf page

```
<h:outputLabel id="myId" value="{Msgs['global_today']}"/>
```

Now I want to see the key in the page, "global_today" not today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way is to rename the properties file, that way JSF wont find any key and you instead of 'today' you will see ???global_today???

If you still want to see the `global_today` you can do the following:

Lets say you have the following in your faces-config.xml

```
<resource-bundle>
    <base-name>my.package.resources.MyText</base-name>
</resource-bundle>
```

Rename the `MyText` into `MyTextExtender`

Then in add `MyTextExtender.java` in the `my.package.resources` package

with the following content:

```
public class MyTextExtender extends ResourceBundle {

    public MyTextExtender() {
        setParent(getBundle("my.package.resources.MyText", FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                .getViewRoot().getLocale()));
    }

    @Override
    public Enumeration<String> getKeys() {
        return parent.getKeys();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object handleGetObject(String key) {
        return key;
        //The code below will try to turn the annoying ???some_key??? 
        //into "some key" (looks better)
        /*try {
            return parent.getObject(key);
        } catch (MissingResourceException e) {
            if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(key)) {
                logger.error("Missing key: " + key + " in the properties", e);
                return key.replace("_", " ");
            } else {
                logger.error("Key was null???", e);
                return "";
            }
        }*/
    }
}
```

Comment: This page (http://jdevelopment.nl/internationalization-jsf-utf8-encoded-properties-files/ ) pointed me already in this direction and that works.

Comment: Well, eventually most JSF related solution comes from **BalusC** :)